# Split a list into multiple lists using lambda expression

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

```
class order {
    Guid employeeId;
    DateTime time;
}
```

I need to filter a list of orders into 4 lists based on the time range. 0-9AM to 1st list, 9AM-2PM to 2nd, 2-6PM to 3rd and 6-12PM to a 4th list.

I am curious if this can be achieved using lambda expressions in a efficient way? otherwise what would be the best way to split the list?

Comment: Do your list contain orders of only a single day?

Comment: I noticed a lot of answers have similar strategies.  I edited my response to discuss the performance implications of using these strategies on a large data set.  Whichever answer you pick, I wanted to make sure you read it because it could make a big difference depending on how big your collection is (or if you're using linq with an ORM).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
var orders = list.OrderBy(o => o.time);
var first  = orders.TakeWhile(o => o.time.TimeOfDay.TotalHours <= 9);
var second = orders.SkipWhile(o => o.time.TimeOfDay.TotalHours <= 9)
                   .TakeWhile(o => o.time.TimeOfDay.TotalHours <= 14);
var third  = orders.SkipWhile(o => o.time.TimeOfDay.TotalHours <= 14)
                   .TakeWhile(o => o.time.TimeOfDay.TotalHours <= 18);
var fourth = orders.SkipWhile(o => o.time.TimeOfDay.TotalHours <= 18);
```

Here's another, maybe more efficient, more flexible and concise approach which uses `Enumerable.GroupBy`:

```
var groups = list.Select(o => new
{
    Order = o,
    DayPart = o.time.TimeOfDay.TotalHours <= 9 ? 1
       : o.time.TimeOfDay.TotalHours > 9  && o.time.TimeOfDay.TotalHours <= 14 ? 2
       : o.time.TimeOfDay.TotalHours > 14 && o.time.TimeOfDay.TotalHours <= 18 ? 3 : 4
})
.GroupBy(x => x.DayPart)
.OrderBy(g => g.Key);

var first = groups.ElementAt(0);  
var second = groups.ElementAt(1);
// ...
```

Comment: Thanks Tim. Your solution is what I was looking for. But my concern was with the performance.

Comment: Performance depends on other factors. How large is the list, what is your desired result(all groups as list, one/multiple groups as IEnumerable for further processing, a subset of each group and so on). Above code does not _materialize_ the query(f.e. by using `ToList()`) so no additional memory is used.

Comment: Tim, I was referring to the number of times the comparisons take place.  For example, imagine you have 4 entries: 5, 10, 17, and 20.  The time comparison happens on the 5 order 4 times instead of once because it's taken once and skipped 3 times.  10 is ignored once, taken once, and skipped twice.  17 is ignored twice, taken once, and skipped once.  You could instead just group once and avoid evaluating those expressions so many times and avoid the sort.

Comment: @D.Patrick: Added another approach to take your objection into account.

Comment: `TimeSpan.Hours` doesn't take minutes into account so an order at, say, 9:30 would incorrectly fall into the first group.  I suggest using `TimeSpan.TotalHours`.

Comment: @RiskyMartin: Yes, you're right. Edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Most readable way would be to use a named function to do the grouping and pass it as a delegate to the GroupBy()

```
var orderGroups = orders.GroupBy(GetOrderGroup)

private int GetOrderGroup(order o)
{
    //implement your groups
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
var first = orders.Where(o => o.time.Hour >= 0 && o.time.Hour < 9);
var second = orders.Where(o => o.time.Hour >= 9 && o.time.Hour < 14);
var third = orders.Where(o => o.time.Hour >= 14 && o.time.Hour < 18);
var fourth = orders.Where(o => o.time.Hour >= 18 && o.time.Hour < 24);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm in OSX right now so I can't test the solution, but I'd probably add a property to my order class to calculate the group.  I feel like your order would reasonably be concerned with this.  So, you could have something like this:

```
class order {
    Guid employeeId;
    DateTime time;

    public int Group { get { return /* check hours of day to group /} }
}
```

Then, it should be as easy as `orders.GroupBy(o => o.Group)`;

If you don't feel like your order should know about the groups, you could make another method where you feel it's more important to define the group.  Then you could still say `orders.GroupBy(o => GetGroupNumber(o))`.

If you still need help next time I'm in Windows, I'll write a snippet for you.

**EDIT:**

I've noticed several of the other answers to this question recommend executing a Where or a Skip-Take strategy (with the overhead of a sort) on the original list for each child list you want to create.

My concern is that there is a performance detriment on large sets.  For example, the four .Where evaluations will execute the comparisons on all of your objects four times despite the fact that the groups are mutually exclusive.

I don't know how many data you have, but for your sake I hope it's a LOT of orders :).  In any event, I'd probably try to do the grouping and comparisons in one iteration like I recommended.  If you don't like that solution, I'd recommend you iterate over the list yourself and built your sets without linq to objects.

Just my two cents.

Comment: Thank you! I did the grouping and the comparison in one iteration.

Comment: `Skip-Take strategy (with the overhead of a sort)` No they don't sort the original list. Their costs are just **O(n)**

Comment: I agree that it's linear time (or somewhat less in some cases), but I'm not evaluating the algorithm.  I'm looking at performance.  Doing the same comparison on the same list 4 times takes 4 times as long.  So, it may be O(n), but it's still 4 times longer than it needs to be.  Do you agree with that?

Comment: Oh, also, I was referring to this line from Tim's answer with the sorting thing: var orders = list.OrderBy(o => o.time);

Answer (score 1):

It's important to use the `DateTime.TimeOfDay.TotalHours` property, which will return the time represented by whole and fractional hours.

```
var endTimes = new List<int>() { 9, 14, 18, 24 };
var results = orders.GroupBy(o => endTimes.First(t => o.time.TimeOfDay.TotalHours < t))
                    .OrderBy(g => g.Key);
```